# Foreword/introduction to the translation

Tags: translation, introduction

I translated a book, and was thinking on writing a foreword to it. Not so much introducing the book (as there is a editor foreword from the original that does that), but as an introduction to the project and my motivations for it. It was independently translated, edited and published.

Is it appropriate? If so, what would be a correct title for such foreword?

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing wrong with writing a foreword to a book; ones written by the translator are sometimes called something like "Translator's Foreword" or "About this Translation", etc.

Whether you should write this foreword is a question that can be answered simply: Is what you want to say of interest to the reader? Will reading this foreword be time well spent?

If you have very little to say but think it's important, , perhaps you can write a few sentences and call them a "Translator's Note" or something similar. However, perhaps there's an interesting story behind the translation; in that case, go ahead and write that foreword.